# How can I embed a youtube feed?

Tags: html

I want to embed the youtube upload page of my channel on my website.
I would like to know how I could do this. iframe doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options available for you: (1) embed the webpage as a blockquote using Embedly, or (2) make a playlist of your uploaded videos and embed the playlist.

1. Use Embedly: The website [Embedly](https://embed.ly/code) uses a script to embed any webpage, including the uploads page of your YouTube channel, into a block quote. You'll be using their script in your HTML, so no guarantees on quality.
2. Make a playlist of your uploaded videos, then embed the playlist into your website by following the instructions on [this page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Youtube's API ... https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

They do have a user uploads feed.

https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=USERNAME

IE for focuspullin channel

https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=focuspullin

It provides a video as a and with a playlists that could be used in a iframe

But I would consider this subject to change. Google's knowledge graph shows completely different, older information, about an RSS feed. Unable to find that and it may no longer exist, [but there are several stackoverflow Q and A that reference it from a few years back.]